# Transparent Bridge pass vlan traffic

Tags: networking

I am trying to add a monitor device to our network and in my mind it will go in between the firewall and main switch.

Internet ---- Firewall ---- New Monitor ---- Main Switch

I am going to run NtopNG on a linux box setup in a transparent bridge configuration. If my mind it should pass all traffic, but I am concerned that it will not push the vlan tagged traffic through.

1. I have created the bride and added the interfaces
2. Gave the bridge an IP address so I can connect remotely
3. Put the device on a test network and its passing traffic fine, but I do not have any vlan traffic to test, other than my production environment.

Will a transparent bridge pass all traffic?

The main switch is a procurve, and the firewall/router is a ASA.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work that way.  You will need multiple bridges, one for each vlan.

See:
https://serverfault.com/questions/414115/linux-vlans-over-bridge

Comment: Could you perhaps include the most important details from the link here?

Comment: But.. why would I copy another StackExchange question into this one?  That seems redundant. I understand if it's just a website / blog post but it's not.